# What is wrong with my chart with Google Chart API

Tags: google-visualization

My chart has a problem in showing data's information as an image below. Please let me know what causes the problem and how to address this one.

***Problem:*** There were 2 strange columns of the Target and Actual Shipment for Week 40. For more details, the Actual Shipment column was 153100.50, be more than a half of the Target Shipment (300000.00). The Actual Shipment for Week 41 has shown nothing. While the Actual Shipment for Week 42 was very low as normal.

***Data:***

```
['WEEK','Target','Actual Shipment','Cum Target','Cum Actual Shipment'],
['Week 40',300000.00,153100.50,300000.00,153100.50],
['Week 41',300000.00,102800.11,600000.00,255900.61],
['Week 42',300000.00,106180.90,900000.00,362081.51]
```

---

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bars are correct, you've set the minValue to 100000, so e.g.
the ratio `BlueBar : RedBar` for Week 40 is `1 : 0.265`

The red line you've drawn in the middle of the blue bar for Week 40 is at 200000, but the half of 300000 is 150000

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your comment it is correct and I just recognize that the chart was from $100,000 not as $0. Is there any way to set the minimum value of the vertical axis?

Comment: This usually should happen by default, how do you draw the chart(chart-type and options )

Comment: That was `ComboChart` and options was `var options = { title: 'TOTAL SHIPMENT WEEKLY BY YEAR 2015', seriesType: 'bars', series: {2: {type: 'line'}, 3: {type: 'line'}}, width: 500, height: 350, vAxis: {format: '$#,###'}, legend: {position: 'right'}, is3D: true, sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0, enableInteractivity: true};`

Comment: I've found the solution to address this problem with `vAxis: {format: '$#,###', viewWindow: { min: 0 } }`